# Selenium Webdriver automation for random text

Tags: java, selenium

I'm fairly new to Selenium Webdriver and am trying to automate the following scenario:

1. User is prompted to enter the answer to a security question.
2. Say the answer is "ANSWER".
3. The screen will display *_ X _ X _ _* where *X* is the letter you have to enter and the rest of the letters are masked.  In this case, User has to click <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> on a keyboard simulator on the screen then continue to answer correctly.
4. The difficult part is that the *X* will be randomly generated each time this screen is accessed.

Any ideas please?

Comment: It is a bad idea to automate these kinds of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

So if this X appears in a text field you can get the value of the text box. parse through the text to identify X marks and replace them with the expected value.

```
element.getText()
```

or

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

so at runtime you will have to capture letters.

Comment: Hi Gosar, thanks for your response. The X is a blank textbox and will be changed randomly - User has to enter the correct letter each time. The HTML code is as follows:
<td class = "BodyText" …>
<span class="QAMask"></span>
<span id = "QALetter1" class ="QALetter" onclick="javascript"…
<span class="QAMask"></span>
<span id = "QALetter2" class ="QALetter" onclick="javascript"…
<span class="QAMask"></span>
<span class="QAMask"></span>
</td>

Any idea if i can search for the class value? If yes,i can do a loop for each letter and input the correct value for the span class equals to QALetter

Comment: try this xpath to identify all the elements with class .//span[contains(@class,'QALetter')] this will give you all the elements with span tag whose class value is QALetter. 
Let me know if you need further assistance.